# How do you hide a class behind an interface when that class contains a package-level method?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

How do you hide the following class behind an interface (and instantiate it using a factory)?:

```
public class TreeNode {
    private List<TreeNode> children;
    private TreeNode parent;

    public void addChild(TreeNode newChild) {
        children.add(newChild);
        newChild.setParent(this);
    }

    public TreeNode getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void removeChild(TreeNode child) {
        children.remove(child);
        child.setParent(null);
    }

    void setParent(TreeNode newParent) {
        if(parent != null) {
            parent.removeChild(this);
        }
        parent = newParent;
    }
}
```

Suppose you were to rename the class to TreeNodeObj  and have it implement the TreeNode interface:

```
class TreeNodeObj implements TreeNode {
    private List<TreeNode> children;
    private TreeNode parent;

    public void addChild(TreeNode newChild) {
        children.add(newChild);
        newChild.setParent(this);
    }
    ... etc. ...
}

public interface TreeNode {
    public void addChild(TreeNode newChild);
    public void removeChild(TreeNode child);
    public TreeNode getParent();
}

public class NodeFactory {
    public static TreeNode createTreeNode() {
        return new TreeNodeObj();
    }
}
```

This code doesn’t compile, because setParent() isn’t defined in the TreeNode interface (since it should not be called directly and should not be exposed outside the package).

The only solution I can think of is to make the following modification:

```
public interface TreeNode extends TreeNodePackageAccess {
    public void addChild(TreeNode newChild);
    public void removeChild(TreeNode child);
    public TreeNode getParent();
}

interface TreeNodePackageAccess {
    void setParent(TreeNode newParent);
}

class TreeNodeObj implements TreeNode {
    …[previous code]…

    public void setParent(TreeNode newParent) { 
        // this method is made public in order to implement TreeNodePackageAccess
        …[previous code]…
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this than with the above strategy? (Also, with the above strategy, setParent() is still accessible from outside the package via reflection, so technically, you don't even get package-level encapsulation with it.)

How do you hide the original class behind an interface, given that it requires a package-level method that shouldn’t be exposed?

Comment: Your design seems flawed. Isn't every `TreeNodeObj` going to implement `addchild()` and  `removeChild()` in exactly the same way? If so, inheritance ("is a") is more appropriate. Is your instructor telling you to use an interface as part of the solution?

Comment: Strange naming. This class is a Tree. You don't need a separate node class. Every node of a tree is a tree.

Comment: [A method declared in an interface without an access modifier is implicitly `public`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4), not package-access.  There are no `protected` or package-access interface methods.

Comment: @ John Bollinger. That's true, however, the entire TreeNodePackageAccess interface only has package-level visibility, so setParent() is inaccessible from outside the package (other than through reflection).

Comment: @Randy Casburn You're right - I should have picked a better example than a generic node in a tree - something that has several varying implementations.

Comment: Sure, @user10264746, but an implementation method cannot have more restrictive access than the interface specifies (necessarily `public` if it's an abstract interface method in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it to the implementation class where needed.  If any implementation of TreeNode is not a TreeNodeObj, throw an exception that indicates it came from an invalid provider.

Java SE already does this.  From [the documentation of the java.nio.file package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/package-summary.html):

> Unless otherwise noted, invoking a method of any class or interface in this package created by one [provider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html) with a parameter that is an object created by another provider, will throw [ProviderMismatchException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/ProviderMismatchException.html).

So your other classes in that package can do things like:

```
@Override
public void add(TreeNode node) {
    if (!(node instanceof TreeNodeObj)) {
        throw new WrongProviderException(
            "Argument was created by a different provider: " + node);
    }

    TreeNodeObj obj = (TreeNodeObj) node;
    obj.setParent(parent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do you hide a class behind an interface when that class contains a package-level method?

As posed, there's nothing special required here.  You can abstract any number, including zero, of a class's *public* methods with an interface.  It is not necessary in any general sense that all methods of the class be mirrored as abstract methods of the interface.

But you seem to mean that you want to represent one or more package-access methods in an interface, and this is not possible.  Interface methods may be only `public` or `private`, and `private` methods are not abstract.  The implementation of an abstract method cannot narrow its access, so the implementation of an abstract interface method must be `public`.

Your idea to split the interface into a package-access superinterface and a public subinterface does not help in any way, even if you were willing to make the implementation method public after all.  Any method declared by the superinterface is inherited by the subinterface and can be accessed through it.